# Condensing several SQL queries into a single query so a parameter can be used for different data types

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, parameters

I'm looking to Condense several SQL Server queries into a single query so a parameter can be used for different data types. These types are dates, or numbers or strings. The parameter is called: @SearchValue.

In a strongly typed DataSet we have the 3 queries listed below.

This is for ASP.Net with a VB.Net code-behind file but I think this question is may also be good for non ASP.Net as well.

I call this one if the user enters a date into a search TextBox:

Query:

```
SELECT ID, PaymentAmount, PaymentDate, WhatWasPaymentFor
  FROM     Payments
 WHERE     (ParentID = @ParentID) AND 
           (PaymentDate = @SearchValue)
```

Call from VB.Net code-behind for the date search query:

```
tblObject = theTableAdapter.GetDataByPaymentDate(dcmParentsId, TextBoxSearch.Text)

If tblObject.Count() > 0 Then
   GridViewSummary.DataSource = tblObject
   GridViewSummary.DataBind()
End If
```

The other ones are for numbers only and the last one is for everything else.

This one is for numbers only:

```
SELECT PaymentDate, PaymentAmount, WhatWasPaymentFor, ID
  FROM Payments
 WHERE (ParentID = @ParentID) AND
       (PaymentAmount = @SearchValue)
```

This one is called when the other 2 queries don't find any data:

```
SELECT PaymentDate, PaymentAmount, WhatWasPaymentFor, ID
  FROM Payments
 WHERE (ParentID = @ParentID) AND
       ((WhatWasPaymentFor LIKE '%' + @SearchValue + '%') OR
        (@SearchValue = 'ALL'))
```

All of this coding works as is and I did it this way because there would be an error if I tried to call .GetDataByPaymentDate with a non date value.

Is there a way to use a single query to handle the searching by dates, numbers, and strings?

*** UPDATES ***

Thanks for all the sample queries. I am trying all of the sample queries in the SQL Server Management Studio to see what results come up.

I this one based on Gordon's query but it does not return any data:

```
DECLARE @SearchValue VARCHAR = '01/01/2012'
DECLARE @SearchType  VARCHAR = 'Dates' 
DECLARE @ParentID    INT = 3

SELECT ID, PaymentAmount, PaymentDate, WhatWasPaymentFor
  FROM Payments cross join
       (select @SearchValue as sv) const
 WHERE ParentID = @ParentID AND
       (case when @SearchType = 'Dates' and ISDATE(const.sv) = 1
                then (case when PaymentDate = CAST(const.sv AS datetime) then 'true' else 'false' end)
             when @SearchType = 'Numbers' and ISNUMERIC(const.sv) = 1
                then (case when PaymentAmount = cast(const.sv as Int) then 'true' else 'false' end)
             when @SearchType = 'Everything Else'
                then (case when WhatWasPaymentFor LIKE '%' + const.sv + '%' OR const.sv='ALL' then 'true' else 'false' end)
   end) = 'true'
```

This is based on the one from gh9 and pulls up data. Thanks gh9:

```
DECLARE @SearchValue VARCHAR = 'Books'
DECLARE @ParentID    INT = 3
DECLARE @PaymentDate DATETIME = NULL
DECLARE @PaymentAmount MONEY = NULL

SELECT ID, PaymentAmount, PaymentDate, WhatWasPaymentFor
  FROM Payments
  WHERE ParentID = @ParentID
    AND (@paymentDate is null OR PaymentDate = @Paymentdate)
    AND (@paymentAmount is null OR paymentAmount = @paymentAmount)
    AND ((@SearchValue is null OR 
    (WhatWasPaymentFor LIKE '%' + @SearchValue  + '%' OR @SearchValue='ALL'))
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lets you take advantage of not having to cast searchvalue to whatever you need, also is a bit more readable. Modify the syntax as needed, but the key idea is to use sql server ability to have null parameters and short circuit logic to evaluate strongly typed parameters instead of casting to the data type you need.

```
@ParentID  INT 
@PaymentAmount INT = NULL
@PaymentDate Datetime = null
@GenericSearchTerm varchar(100) = null  

AS
BEGIN
SELECT
  ID,
  PaymentAmount,
  PaymentDate,
  WhatWasPaymentFor
FROM Payments
WHERE @ParentID = @ParentID
  AND ( (@paymentDate is null OR PaymentDate = @Paymentdate))
        AND (@paymentAmount is null OR paymentAmount = @paymentAmount))
        AND ( @GenericSearchTerm is null OR ((WhatWasPaymentFor LIKE '%' + @GenericSearchTerm  + '%' OR @SearchValue='ALL'))
```

EDIT:updated answer per @andriyM comments

Comment: It should be "ID = @ID AND (... IS NULL OR ...) **AND** (... IS NULL OR ...) **AND** (... IS NULL OR ...)", though.

Comment: One more advantage to this approach is that it allows you to search by more than one criterion.

Comment: @anriym when you said it should be "id =@id and (... is null or ...) how is that different from what I have?

Comment: Your condition seems to follow the same pattern except is has ORs instead of the ANDs that I emphasized in bold. It also seems to have one extra `)` (after `@paymentAmount`) and to miss another `)` (at the end).

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a third parameter of @SearchType with possible values of ('datetime','int', or 'nvarchar') and using it in your WHERE clause to cast the @SearchValue to appropriate type for comparison.  Something like:

```
SELECT
  ID,
  PaymentAmount,
  PaymentDate,
  WhatWasPaymentFor
FROM Payments
WHERE @ParentID = @ParentID
  AND (
        (@SearchType = 'datetime' AND PaymentDate = CAST(@SearchValue AS datetime))
        OR
        (@SearchType = 'int' AND PaymentAount = CAST(@SearchValue AS int))
        OR
        (@SearchType = 'nvarchar' AND 
          (WhatWasPaymentFor LIKE '%' + @SearchValue + '%' OR @SearchValue='ALL')
        );
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try and let you know if it works for us.

Comment: I get this error: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime. when I sent it "int" Seems the query is performing the CAST for datetime before reaching the "int" part.

Comment: I didn't error check my query.  I wrote it in notepad.  Make sure that the values you pass in for the @SearchValue are in a format that is valid for your system.

Answer (score 0):

This is inspired by Bstateham's answer, but it does two things differently.  First, it stores the values in a table, turning them from constants into variables.  Second, it uses the `case` because that guarantees shortcircuiting.

This results in something like:

```
SELECT ID, PaymentAmount, PaymentDate, WhatWasPaymentFor
FROM Payments cross join
     (select @SearchValue as sv) const
WHERE @ParentID = @ParentID AND
      (case when @SearchType = 'datetime' and ISDATE(const.sv) = 1
            then (case when PaymentDate = CAST(const.sv AS datetime) then 'true' else 'false' end)
            when @SearchType = 'int' and ISNUMERIC(const.sv) = 1
            then (case when PaumentAmount = cast(const.sv as Int) then 'true' else 'false' end)
            when @SearchType = 'nvarchar'
            then (case when WhatWasPaymentFor LIKE '%' + const.sv + '%' OR const.sv='ALL' then 'true' else 'false' end)
       end) = 'true'
```

I also added in validation checks for the conversion to integer and date (not perfect, but will help).  Also, you should probably name the @SearchType after the destination field rather than the type.  However, I've kept the version with the type name.